# An extra Sql record is being added everytime

Tags: php, sql, chat, message

I am working on a chatting web-application. The problem is that whenever the page is loaded everytime an empty message is inserted into the database.

The code is as below

```
          <!--   Insert MySQL datbase into HTML     -->
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$query = "SELECT * FROM shouts ORDER BY id Desc LIMIT 8";
$shouts = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>



                  <!--   Insert MySQL datbase into HTML     -->
     <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shouts)) : ?>
      <li> <?php echo $row['shout']; ?> <b>&nbspSent at&nbsp</b><?php echo $row['Time']; ?></li>
          <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <footer>
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <label>Shout Text: </label>
      <input type="text" name="shout" placeholder="Enter your message here">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SHOUT!" >
    </form>
      <?php 
                  <!--   Insert  into MySQL datbase     -->

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
$sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (name,shout) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[shout]')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
echo "Records added successfully.";
} else
{
  echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>   
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It only makes sense that if you have an `INSERT INTO...` statement it will insert a new row to your database. Your code does exactly what you wrote. What is the problem?

Comment: @Dekel is right. everytime you reload your page, your php code is executed. you might want to put some sort of condition before inserting

Comment: what would that condition be @FranckNgako

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST["name"])){
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tru");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO shouts (name,shout) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[shout]')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

With an if sentece you have it solved. It will only add a record if the POST name variable isset.

Comment: i would like to debug you code ..1) please give proper ending bracket at first if isset line ['name'] currently it is ['name') .2) remove that <!-- comment --> i dont know how php will interpret  it. Bcas thats not how we commnt in php.

Comment: The bug has been removed the way you told to use isset . But along with this I had to also remove last line of the code  that was   mysqli_close($link);  Otherwise an error used to come saying Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tru\index.php on line 57  ... I think its a bad habit not to close mysqli link. Do you have any way out to this @ Eric Liebstreich

Comment: By the way thanks for giving this logic @Eric Liebsreich

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion@akashraigade

Answer (score 1):

You unconditionally `insert` a row, so this is kind of expected. So, what should be the condition? Naturally, on page load you do not want to `insert` a shout, only on POST. So you need to test whether the request is a post:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // insert the row
}
```

But even if it is a POST, you need to test whether it is valid, so check name and shout:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if ((isset($_POST["name"])) && (isset($_POST["shout"])) && ($_POST["name"]) && ($_POST["shout"])) {
        //insert the row
    }
}
```

Watch out for [SQL injection](http://lp.checkmarx.com/prevent-sql-injection-new/?utm_source=google-ppc&utm_content=55080840231&utm_medium=cpc&utm_keyword=sql%20injection&utm_campaign=Application_Security_ROW_Remarketing_Search-2016&leadsource=PPC&lead_sub_source__c=google&utm_query=gc&gclid=CjwKEAjw19vABRCY2YmkpO2OzTsSJAAzEt8skEy2UiWEaRylL_lfaUIOuqMwDadTrS0Rxpn5JURZgxoCOrXw_wcB) though.

Comment: Thanks it works now... but for that I have to remove the last line of code that is to close the connection. The line is Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tru\index.php on line 57

Comment: @HNSingh, connecting, inserting and disconnecting should be inside the if shown in this answer, your second problem was that you try to close a connection you did not open. This happened when you loaded the page in the browser, the if condition was false and $link was not initialized. If the answer was helpful you might consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark.